# Going from knowing only 2 points to knowing the entire graph?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

So, I am trying to figure out the period of a binary orbit given the masses of both objects and the maximum and minimum distance between the 2 objects. I first tried seeing if I could come to the answer algebraically. But once I got to calculating the velocity, I was told to equate the centripetal force with the gravitational force. But this gave me the wrong velocity. I wasn't looking for minimum velocity to maintain a circular orbit, I was looking for the orbital velocity of the object at minimum and maximum distance. But just algebraically solving the centripetal force equation for velocity, I got the minimum velocity needed to maintain a circular orbit. So now that I know that I can't simply do algebra to solve this problem, I am going to have to use calculus. Here is the problem:

### Problem

There are 2 masses, one with 90% the mass of earth and one with 50% the mass of earth. Let's call the bigger one m1 and the smaller one m2. m1 has a radius of 95% that of earth and m2 has a radius of 40% that of earth. These 2 masses are in a binary orbit. The minimum distance in this binary orbit is the earth-moon distance. The maximum distance in the binary orbit is 2.25 * the earth-moon distance. At minimum distance, the 2 masses are at their maximum velocity and at maximum distance, they are at their minimum velocity. Calculate the period of the binary orbit using Newton's laws of motion and the Law of Universal Gravitation. Use calculus if necessary.

### Relevant equations

$$F_g=G∗\frac{m1∗m2}{r^2}$$
$$F=ma$$
$$F_{cent}=m∗\frac{v^2}{r}$$

Algebraically, all I can calculate is the gravitational force and gravitational acceleration at 2 points for the 2 masses. Those being the minimum and maximum distance. So how am I supposed to go from knowing the force and acceleration at 2 points to knowing the entire graph of the orbital velocity? Once I know the entire graph, calculating the period of the orbit should be easy just looking at the graph or doing some algebra.

Since the acceleration changes, the minimum number of derivative operators needed to arrive at a constant value is 3. But there may be no point where the derivative is 0 everywhere. If there is no such point where the xth derivative = 0 everywhere, then I can't simply do a chain of antiderivatives to arrive at the velocity graph.

**So how can I go from knowing the force and acceleration at 2 points for each mass to knowing the entire velocity graph?**

Comment: This might belong in PhysicsSE.

Comment: You're talking about the classic "two body problem". There's a lot that could be said about it, but Wikipedia is a great place to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem

Comment: You can't equate the centripital force to the gravitational force because the distance is changing at those points.